# python built in server not loading css file

Tags: python, django, frameworks

Why does not it work in Django? There is error in the browser like that.

```
its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

In file html there is :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'nowy.css' %}">
```

In settings.py it looks like:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Dirs are: app > static > nowy.css

I can't find where is the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

this can be caused by your settings static variables, or your addressing to your css file.
first try to check settings.
did you include STATICFILES_DIRS ?

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

and also try checking template settings.
did you include loader?

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
    ,
    'APP_DIRS': False,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
        'loaders': [
            'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
            'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

now try to check the path to your css file.

- project
- app_name

  - static

    - app_name

      - style.css

in your html it would be like this

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "app_name/style.css" %}">
```